# S3 hosted website with Cloudflare returns 404 status code for any route

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare

I have an S3 hosted website working well behind Cloudflare with the following:

[image: ss1]

`example.com/` works fine

`example.com/test` also works but the document itself in the network tab is returning 404, naturally, because /test doesn't exist on S3.

This is a problem for SEO, how do I configure Cloudflare to treat 404s as 200s?

In Cloudfront I usually do this:

[image: ss2]

But I can find no corresponding configuration in Cloudflare. Will this have to be done in a Cloudflare worker? What did people do before Workers existed?

Comment: What do you want to achieve for the route "http://example.com/test" ? Redirect, or just a 200 response. What should be displayed in the browser for that route?

Comment: /test would be a legitimate route, so I'd like it to return 200 when /index.html gets served up for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out people just didn't host on S3 with Cloudflare before workers, and if they did, they didn't care/notice that their routes would return 404.

Anyway, this is the solution with Cloudflare workers to force the return code of 200:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(fetchAndApply(event.request))
})

async function fetchAndApply(request) {
  let originalResponse = await fetch(request)

  const contentType = originalResponse.headers.get("Content-Type")

  // Only bother with index pages (not assets)
  if (contentType && contentType.includes("text/html")) {

    // Force 404's from S3 to return as 200 to prevent Google indexing issues
    let response = new Response(originalResponse.body, {
        ...originalResponse,
        status: 200, 
        statusText: 'OK'
      }
    )

    // Don't cache index.html
    response.headers.set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0')

    return response
  }

  return originalResponse
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you can use this approach from the AWS docs.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html
Example #3 at the bottom of the document page.

This is S3 bucket for the demo.

> EDIT: removed the URL, it served the purpose that was usable only to
>   author of the question.

Here is short example. Which will redirect to "home" if not found.

```
<RoutingRules>
<RoutingRule>
<Condition>
  <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals >
</Condition>
<Redirect>
  <HostName>BUCKETNAME.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>
  <ReplaceKeyWith></ReplaceKeyWith>
</Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

Comment: Thanks. The /test route should be found, it serves up all requests with index.html for my SPA. Your example seems to fully redirect all requests to / (removing the URL path)

Comment: what should test route return then?

Comment: @Titan if you describe simple case scenario, two of us can resolve this quickly I beleive.

Comment: I have a Vue SPA on S3. S3 is set to send all requests to /index.html (including "error documents"). The root of the website returns the app and a 200 code for the document. /test returns the app as expected, but in the network tab when looking at the response code of the document it's 404. I believe this is because S3 is treating /test as a missing asset and sending back that error code, despite correctly serving it up with index.html. This is usually solved in Cloudflare as I described in screenshots above. I need to know the equivalent in Cloudfront.

Comment: I beleive then that this post will solve your issues. https://medium.com/@joecrobak/production-deploy-of-a-single-page-app-using-s3-and-cloudfront-d4aa2d170aa3

Comment: Yes as my original post describes, I’m aware of how to do it using CloudFront, but I’ve switched to CloudFlare and I need to know how to do it there. I don’t want double CDNs